# Can I pass an array of enums with Jetpack Navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

Why can't I add an enum array argument using Jetpack Navigation?
What I do:

```xml
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.MyFragment"
    android:label="fragment_my"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_my">

    <argument
        android:name="enums"
        app:argType="com.example.MyEnum[]" />

</fragment>
```

But it cannot be built because this error happens:
`Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<MyEnum> but Array<(out) Parcelable!>? was expected`

I could use Kotlin's sealed classes with `@Parcelize` annotation but it seems to be just wrong. What am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: i'm curious, could you actually achieve this without using the navigation component ? can you set an enum type to a fragment as an argument ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody

I don't create fragments manually. Jetpack Navigation Component does that. The answer is no.

Comment: i'm not talking about the navigation component at all, i'm asking if you _were_ to create a fragment and try to set an enum to it, would that work _without_ the navigation component ? because if it doesn't, i'd say it makes sense that it isn't possible _with_ the navigation component

Comment: Right, internally it uses `Bundle` and it doesn't have a method like `putSerializableArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out it is not really possible (thanks to @a_local_nobody). Jetpack Navigation Component simply uses `android.os.Bundle` inside and it doesn't have a method like `putSerializableArray`.
I came up with two walkarounds: to use Kotlin's sealead classes with `@Parcelize` annotation like I wrote above and to send an array of `Int`s and then parse them to an enum if you want. You can use either of them, they both suck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you parcelize your class correctly? It should be like this:

**1. Import following plugin to the build gradle file (app):**

```
id 'kotlin-parcelize'
```

**2. Add `@Parcelize` Notation and Implement `Parcelable`:**

```
@Parcelize                  //add annotaion
data class MarsProperty(
    val id: String,
    val imageUrl: String,
    val type: String,
    val price: Double
) : Parcelable
```

Comment: I actually wanted to avoid passing Parcelable because it looks massive and redundant. It would be much easier to just pass an array of Enums. That's what my question was about. 

But answering your question, yes I do exactly that but I don't want to do that.